# Android text clicking a portion to fire an intent similar to an href link

Tags: android, text, android-intent, textview

In one of my android screens, I want to have a checkbox and text such as this:

```
 _
|_| I have agreed to the *terms of service*.
```

The text `I have agreed to the *terms of service*` is in a constant string in my /values/strings.xml file. I know I can make the text I want a link with html

```
I have agreed to the <a href="some.website.com">*terms of service*</a>.
```

But is there a way to make it so that instead of a website being launched, I can launch a custom or display a dialog box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2009/10/29/clickable-urls-in-android-textviews/